# React - Creating and deleting list items dynamically

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I work on ToDo List to practice my React skill, but I struggle with one thing.

Using .map() function, I'm creating a list with list items. Each item has  and  element. Here's a code:

```
tasksFiltered.map((task, keyID) => {
    return (<li key={task.id} className={'todo-list__list-item'}>
        <span>{task.text}</span> 
        <button key={task.id} onClick={() => this.props.deleteTask(task.id, tasks)}>
        <FaTrashAlt />
        </button>
    </li>)
```

As you can see, the buttons have onClick event and the function deleteTask is created in the Parent Component. The structure looks like this

```
  deleteTask = (id) => {
 //// code here
}
```

and the state is in Parent Component as well

```
  state = {
    imputValue: 'Type new item',
    inputText: '',
    tasks: []
  }
```

After summiting the form, I create a new task and I add it as a next element to the tasks array. The new task structure looks like that:

```
    const newTask = {
  id: (Math.random() + Math.random()),
  text: this.state.inputText,
  isDeleted: false,
}
```

My problem is I do not know how to create a code inside deleteTask function. I would like to check what id has the li item where this button exists and then change this specific object by this.setState and changing `isDeleted: false`, to `isDeleted: !this.isDeleted`

Comment: Sounds like you've already described how to solve your problem? What exactly are you hung up on?

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't get exactly what is happening in your app, but since this is a ToDo list I'll assume that you want to click on the item and delete it from the DOM, but I couldn't understand if you really want to delete the item from your array or just hide it so it won't be shown to the user. I am saying this because if you really want to delete it you don't need the `isDeleted` property. I'll give you two examples, one for each situation.

1- Delete the item from the array:

I imagine that `tasksFiltered` is an array of objects and each object has an `id` property. If this is the case you can just use `filter` to exclude the item you want and update `tasksFiltered`.

```
const deleteTask = id => {
  let newTasks = [...this.state.tasksFiltered]
  newTasks = newTasks.filter(item => item.id !== id)
  this.setState({tasksFiltered: newTasks})
}
```

2- Remove item from the DOM but keep it in the array:

You can use `forEach` to update the property `isDeleted` and check if `isDeleted===false` within the `map` before rendering the elements to the DOM:

```
const deleteTask = id => {
  let newTasks = [...this.state.tasksFiltered]
  newTasks.forEach(item => {
    if (item.id === id) {
      item.isDeleted = true
    }
  })
  this.setState({tasksFiltered: newTasks})
}
```

map:

```
tasksFiltered.map(task => {
    if (task.isDeleted === false) {
        return <li key={task.id} className={'todo-list__list-item'}>
            <span>{task.text}</span> 
            <button key={task.id} onClick={() => this.props.deleteTask(task.id, tasks)}>
            <FaTrashAlt />
            </button>
        </li>
    }
})
```

https://codepen.io/WegisSilveira/pen/YzVErde?editors=1111